# Exibir dados do banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Quero exibir varios dados em uma pagina mas ele aparece somente um, ao em vez de aparecer a imagem de cada cadastro por exemplo ele aparece somente a de um
que é a do ultimo cadastro feito.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM animestb LIMIT 20000";
$con = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($con)) {
  $nome = $row['nome'];
  $link = $row['link'];
  $img = $row['img'];
  $id = $row['id'];
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM animestb");
$sql->execute();

while($ln = $sql->fetchObject()){
     echo "<img src='".$ln->img."'>"
}
```

Por favor, nao utilize `mysql_query` o mesmo foi descontinuado. utilize ou [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Conexao PDO

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);
?>
```

Consulta PDO

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$sql->execute();

while($ln = $sql->fetchObject()){

}
```

Comment: Quando uso mysqli da esse erro: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: é porque nao e so trocar mysql_ para mysqli. use PDO eé melhor ainda. vou te dar um exemplo atualizando a resposta